# How to inherit from Python None

Tags: python

I would like to create a class that inherites from `None`.

Tried this:

```
class InvalidKeyNone(None):
    pass
```

but that gives me:

```
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    cannot create 'NoneType' instances
```

What would be the correct solution that gives me a type that behaves exactly like `None` but which I can type test?

```
foo = InvalidKeyNone()
print(type(foo))
>>> InvalidKeyNone
```

[EDIT]

I want to do this because I am creating a selection scheme on Python datastructures:

```
bar = select(".foo.bar.[1].x", {"foo":{"bar":[{"x":1}, {"x":2}], "baz":3})
print(bar)
>> 2
```

And I want to be able to determine whether I get a None because the selected value is None or because the key was not found.
HOWEVER it must return a (ducktyped) None that behaves exactly like a None. No exceptions or custom type returning here.

[EDIT]

Ok, so the consensus is: can't be done. Which although unsatisfactory is a valid answer. Since I really want the default behavior to have it return a None when the key is not present I think I will have the select eat a param to switch to exception throwing when appropriate. Thanks.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: I am as surprise as karthikr, I don't see the point. Give us more information on that

Comment: (Most likely) You cannot create an instance because `None` is a singleton

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve with this?  There is bound to be a better (and feasible) way to do it.

Comment: It may be of type NoneType but it's a singleton... you'll need to explain the use case

Comment: To expand on the singleton point, even assuming such an object could be constructed, using it would break half of Python's stdlib, because the `if x is None:` idiom used everywhere tests object *identity*.  Since that pattern is the recommended one, there is no way to construct some None-like type such that instances of it will behave exactly like `None`.

Comment: @RickyA how about using a [Null Object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) when the selection does not match?

Comment: You also don't want to rely on type checking - this is an anti-pattern in Python. You should instead check if an object supports an interface; more of a "try it and see" rather than "check and react". It also looks like what you need is a custom Exception.

Comment: _"behaves exactly like None"_ - as far as I'm aware, `None` has no non-trivial special behavior

Comment: "HOWEVER it must return a (ducktyped) None that behaves exactly like a None. No exceptions or custom type returning here."  Why?  Everyone else seems to get by without this unusual need.  The standard idiom is to use a custom sentinel, whether a fully specified class type or simply `sentinel = object()`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`None` is a [constant](http://docs.python.org/2/library/constants.html), the sole value of `types.NoneType` (for [v2.7](https://docs.python.org/2/library/constants.html?highlight=nonetype#None), for [v3.x](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html?highlight=nonetype#None))

Anyway, when you try to inherit from `types.NoneType`

```
from types import NoneType

class InvalidKeyNone(NoneType):
    pass

foo = InvalidKeyNone()
print(type(foo))
```

you'll get this error

> *Python 2*
>
> TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
>       type 'NoneType' is not an acceptable base type
>
> *Python 3*
>
> ImportError: cannot import name 'NoneType'

in short, you cannot inherit from `NoneType`

Anyway, why would want a class to inherit `NoneType`?

Comment: In python 3 you could do: type(None) and it returns NoneType

Comment: I would like to be able to inherit from `NoneType`, e.g. for dumping to YAML I would then have multiple types that all behave like `None` but that  can be represented in different ways in YAML (`NULL`, `~`, `null`, the empty scalar, and `Null`)

Comment: `class Foo(type(None)):
TypeError: type 'NoneType' is not an acceptable base type`  — :-D

Comment: You asked, Anyway, why would want a class to inherit `NoneType`?  It would be nice to inherit from `NoneType` in order to make null nodes for linked lists and trees. `None.left = x` raises an exception because `None` doesn't have an attribute named `left`. For null nodes of a linked list, you can change that behavior

Answer (score 15):

Subclassing None does not make sense, since it is a singleton and There Can Be Only One.  You say you want a class with the same behaviour, but None does not have any behaviour!

If what you really want is a unique placeholder that you can return from a function to indicate a special case then simplest way to do this is to create a unique instance of object:

```
InvalidKey = object()

result = doSomething()
if result is InvalidKey:
    ...
```

Comment: Note that the difference here is that `bool(None)` is `False`, whereas `bool(InvalidKey)` is `True`

Comment: The solution would be to create a singleton instance of a custom class with `__nonzero__` set to return false.

Comment: Subclassing `None` makes a lot of sense when using typing with optional values and sentinels. `param: Optional[str] = DefaultNone` This allows distinguishing between the default value and explicitly passed `None`.

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to do it, at least definitely not until you do some unreadable black magic.

You should probably use exceptions.

Comment: This. Subclass `KeyError` and have your code raise that instead of the standard `KeyError`.