# None Wrapper in Python 3

Tags: python

I need to create a wrapper for each type, like int, float, list, etc. The reason I need to do this is that a have to add an additional property to them. With normal data types it is quite easy, I just subclass them and add the property:

```
class IntWrapper(int):        
    def __init__(self, value):
        super().__init__()
```

And then:

```
my_int = IntWrapper(1)
setattr(my_int, 'my_prop', 'foo')
my_int.my_prop  #  prints 'foo'
my_int  #  prints 1
my_int + 1  #  prints 2
```

So far, so good... now, I know there are good reasons for the NoneType not being allowed to be subclassed. I have read [How to inherit from Python None](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17424516/3154357) and I see that most people don't see the point. Still, I need to somehow "fake" an object that behaves exactly in the same way like the IntWrapper from above. I don't require it to return 'NoneType' when typing `type(NoneWrapper)`, so it does not have to be a perfect clone. But I want it to return a real `None` (literally nothing) when just typing the object name:

```
my_none = NoneWrapper(None)
my_none  #  prints empty line
```

From the above mentioned post I've seen that people might suggest a custom exception but that is not a solution for me in this case. Is there a way to build a NoneWrapper that behaves exactly like the IntWrapper with respect to its own type?

**EDIT:**
Since it seems to be of high interest WHY this is needed, I will give the full context:
I am building a configuration parser which basically makes the content of a JSON configuration file available as object chain (similar to Javascript objects with dot separator). This config object behaves very similar to a dictionary but has some additional advantages like backlinks. I can look at any configuration option and trace back the path to the root node it is attached to.

So, when parsing the dictionary (which stems from the JSON file) recursively, it builds the object chain. Once it detects a type or constant at a leaf position of that dictionary, it adds this wrapper as a last element in the chain. The backlink property is needed on all wrappers, also None.

Comment: This object is not going to behave like `None` in any useful way, beyond perhaps having the same `bool` output. The primary use of `None` is for its identity, which your object cannot share.

Comment: What's the reason of creating this type of wrapper?

Comment: Is **None** a type?

Comment: Why do you need to annotate `None` with additional attributes? Can't you use an external structure, that you relate to each object via weak references, perhaps?

Comment: @KonradSitarz: The reason is the additional property I want to set on the Wrapper, as mentioned in the post.

Comment: @Steve: nope, they'd have to subclass `type(None)`, which also resists subclassing. They'd have the same problem with `bool`. Both types explicitly forbid subclassing because there should only ever be the 3 instances `False`, `True` and `None`, and subclassing would allow you to bypass that restriction.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I haven't found a good way of doing this so far. I think the wrapper would perfectly fit the purpose. See also my edit.

Comment: What do you want from this wrapper of None? It has to have the backlink, what other requirements do you have?

Comment: You can't have what you want though, I'm offering you a viable alternative.

Comment: @loxosceles: and for your described usecase I'd simply not extend this to scalar types. String, number and boolean objects, as well as `None` don't need to have further dot-notation support. In other words, I'd only expect your JSON configuration object to apply to the containers.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: `slice` is another example of an unsubclassable built-in type. Unlike the others, it's not due to any singleton aspect of its instances AFAICT. Probably just limited because it's largely intended to be created implicitly by slice syntax, and for speed, in CPython, they made it impossible to subclass to avoid needing to write "slow paths" for `slice` subclasses, leaving only the fast paths based on `slice`s concrete C API.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I'd be grateful for any good alternative. Could you explain with a little bit more of detail, please?

Comment: @dedObed: Really nothing else. Basically, as if I assigned 'None' to a variable and then on top I'd be able to set this property with `setattr()`.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: yes, there are more. `type(Ellipsis), type(NotImplemented)` (both also a singletons). But `slice` may just have forgotten to set `Py_TPFLAGS_BASETYPE`; e.g. types defined in C cannot be used as base classes by default unless explicitly marked as such.

Comment: @loxosceles: I don't believe you :-) I guess you want to at least (1) access that property and (2) check if a given object is this `null` from a JSON. Any other operations? Printing? Arithmetics?

Comment: @loxosceles: for your usecase, just don't subclass the scalar types. Focus only on the containers. For other usecases, out-of-band data associations can be done with [weak references](https://docs.python.org/3/library/weakref.html), so as not to keep the subjects alive unneeded.

Comment: @dedObed: (1) correct :) (2) not needed. Other operations: Example: `a = NoneWrapper(None)`, then: `if a is None: do stuff`. In other words, `a` should RETURN a "real" None now, but also have the backlink.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I will look into weak references, seems the way to go. If you want to post a working example, and it fits my problem, I would accept it as answer.

Comment: @loxosceles: Ok, that requirement cannot be met, period. The `if a is None` test does what `is` is for: test for identity. And there is only one `None`.

Answer (score -2):

All the functions/methods in python returns None if 'return' isn't declared or just returning that object directly.
If you want to not see any value as a return you haven't to use print for display.